# iOS 10 Beta 7 sdk not supported in Xcode 8 Beta 6

Tags: ios10, xcode8-beta6

I just updated **iOS 10 beta 7** which is not readable in **xcode 8 beta 6** and I can't find any update for xcode beta.

It is throwing "Unable to read from device" in Organizer

Comment: My device is in iOS10 beta 7 and Xcode 8 beta 6. My device is ok with Xcode.
Try to reboot your device and your Mac.

Comment: You are right..

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 8 beta 6 was released on August 15, and iOS 10 beta 7 was released on August 19. So we need to wait till Xcode 8 beta 7 is released.

Comment: Yes, I knew. But so far they rolled out beta updates for both at the same time.

Comment: this is such bullshit from apple! why would they do this leaving everyone that updated the dev phone not being able to use it

Comment: Per Apple's guidelines, the betas are distributed to developers in order to begin/update projects for the new iOS version. This move seems to contradict that statement quite a lot.

Answer (score 1):

After updating the device to iOS 10 beta 8, reset the network settings.
Settings -> General -> Reset -> Reset Network Settings
Then connect to the Xcode 8 beta 6. It'll work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Reboot both your iPhone with beta 7 o beta 8 and the computer running Xcode beta 6.

I originally only booted the phone and was still having issues. After I booted both of them, I can now use my phone again.